# How do I apply nodal analysis to this circuit?

Tags: nodal-analysis

Looking at the diagram below, I see the formation of a supernode that is different from the ones I've encountered before and I really don't know how to go about it.

[image]

How can nodal analysis be used to solve this circuit?

Answer (score 0):

Take the node 'b' to be the reference. Apply KCL at node 'a'. You will get an equation with two unknowns: 'io' and 'i1'. Also, in the left loop, i1=-io. You now have two equations and two unknowns. Solve this to get the values of the unknowns.

Comment: Note that the voltage across the 2 ohm resistance is 1 V. So, the current through the 2 ohm resistance can be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the circuit we want to analyze is given by:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fljknx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_0+\text{I}_2\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\displaystyle\left(-\text{n}\cdot\text{I}_0\right)-\text{V}_\text{i}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Using \$(2)\$ we can rewrite \$(1)\$ as follows:

$$
\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}=\text{I}_0+\frac{\displaystyle\left(-\text{n}\cdot\text{I}_0\right)-\text{V}_\text{i}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{I}_0=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}}{\displaystyle1-\frac{\displaystyle\text{n}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_1\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2-\text{n}\right)}\tag3
$$